# Rewrite multiple url apache24

Tags: apache-2.2

My set up under Tomcat

```
Tomcat70
 webapps
   traffic_controller
   adminOrder
```

I want to direct traffic via Apache with following rules

`www.myip/admin` should be directed to `www.myip.com/` [adminOrder is the root]

`www.myip.com/*` should be directed to `www.myip.com/traffic_controller` which after some data collection will direct user to `www.myip.com/`

```
 where * = users, or anysuffix
```

Tried these 2:

- [Multiple RewriteConditions: How to chain them before a set of rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305987/multiple-rewriteconditions-how-to-chain-them-before-a-set-of-rules)
- [How to Redirect All urls to a new domain in apache, except one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10629430/how-to-redirect-all-urls-to-a-new-domain-in-apache-except-one)